# Problem installing HPLIP cups

Tags: printing, hardware, hplip

I'm having trouble setting up my wireless printer HP Officejet 6700 in Ubuntu 16.04. It says that it's missing cups. Furthermore, it says:

```
A package manager '[mmcqd/0rpmb] ' appears to be running. Please quit the package manager and press enter to continue (i=ignore, r=retry*, f=force, q=quit) :
```

I don't know what `mmcqd/0rpmb` is. When I did a google search, it seemed to be some sort of error with HPLIP. When I checked synaptic, it seems that I already had cups installed.

```
(xenial)zivoid@localhost:~/Downloads$ sh "hplip-3.17.4.run"
Creating directory hplip-3.17.4
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.17.4 Self Extracting Archive.................................................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.4)
HPLIP Installer ver. 5.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Installer log saved in: hplip-install_Fri-12-May-2017_14:14:48.log

/
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.
-


INSTALLATION MODE
-----------------
Automatic mode will install the full HPLIP solution with the most common options.
Custom mode allows you to choose installation options to fit specific requirements.

Please choose the installation mode (a=automatic*, c=custom, q=quit) : 
Initializing. Please wait...


INTRODUCTION
------------
This installer will install HPLIP version 3.17.4 on your computer.
Please close any running package management systems now (YaST, Adept, Synaptic, Up2date, etc).


DISTRO/OS CONFIRMATION
----------------------
Distro appears to be Ubuntu 16.04.

Is "Ubuntu 16.04" your correct distro/OS and version (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


ENTER USER PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the sudoer (zivoid)'s password: 


INSTALLATION NOTES
------------------
Enable the universe/multiverse repositories. Also be sure you are using the Ubuntu "Main" Repositories. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more information.  Disable the CD-ROM/DVD source if you do not have the Ubuntu installation media inserted in the drive.

Please read the installation notes. Press <enter> to continue or 'q' to quit: 


SECURITY PACKAGES
-----------------
AppArmor is installed. 
AppArmor protects the application from external intrusion attempts making the application secure

Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes, n=no*, q=quit) ? y


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
cups                 base                 REQUIRED            
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)
A package manager '[mmcqd/0rpmb] ' appears to be running. Please quit the package manager and press enter to continue (i=ignore, r=retry*, f=force, q=quit) :
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: This could help you. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/260102 However I'm unsure if it's a bug or not! Leaving it open

Comment: I'm trying to get my printer/scanner working so that I can print/scan things from my laptop. I copy+pasted everything from my terminal into this text document: https://pastebin.com/tCs5M7GT.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem.

After doing some researching and getting nowhere, I tried to ignore the fact that the process is marked as a package manager, and the install proceeded to complete as usual.

I am really not sure what this process does, but It did not stop running the apt-get install that the script runs for the dependencies... (or any other instance of apt-get running by itself).